# Convert this raw sql to Eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Can someone please help me convert this sql to Eloquent, my database over 100k rows, i cant run it normaly, it got hang. I try query same table but notworking.

This is my query:

```
select id, file_id, server, chapter, data 
from chapters c1 
where server = 'sg' 
AND chapter not in (select chapter 
                    from chapters c2 
                    where server = 'hk' 
                    AND c1.file_id= c2.file_id)
```

P/S: Sorry abt my language too bad <3

Comment: Check out [this tool](https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/). It is an online raw sql to eloquent converter.

Comment: If the raw query hangs, the Eloquent version probably will too. Do you have appropriate indexes on `server`, `chapter`, and `file_id`?

Comment: @Innovin Just for reference. That converter does not seem to like that raw query

Comment: @RiggsFolly the convertor is not entirely accurate for complex queries.

Comment: @ceejayoz That's just about right. It probably hangs dues to the number of rows. I mean, 100k is actually a lot to select all

Answer (score 1):

```
Chapters::select('id', 'file_id', 'server', 'chapter', 'data')
->where('server', 'sg')
->whereRaw('(select chapter from chapters c2 where server = 'hk' AND c1.file_id= c2.file_id'')
```